# Cannot SSH into CentOS 7 VM from Ubuntu - "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: ssh, centos, openssh

I cloned this VM and changed the IP. In doing so it apparently wiped the `~/.ssh` directory. I have since recreated it but I still cannot SSH into the Cent OS 7 VM. This is what I get when I try an Ubuntu endpoint:

```
me@Ubuntu01:/mnt/$ ssh -v -C -A -X -p 222 CentOS-7-LAN
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to centos-7-lan [192.168.3.28] port 222.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.3.28 port 222: Resource temporarily unavailable
ssh: connect to host centos-7-lan port 222: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Something is wrong with the SSH config on the VM, but I'm not sure what is it exactly. I've tried from Putty, MobaXTerm...they all let me input the username, then hang indefinitely.